# How to configure embedded-linux USB?

Tags: linux, usb, embedded-linux

Why doesn't [this](http://designsomething.org/leopardboard/f/23/p/743/2753.aspx#2753) correctly configure file_storage device USB?

On the embedded-linux target:

```
/ # modprobe g_file_storage file=/dev/mmcblk0
musb_hdrc: version 6.0, cppi-dma, peripheral, debug=0
musb_hdrc: USB Peripheral mode controller at fec64000 using DMA, IRQ 12 
g_file_storage gadget: File-backed Storage Gadget, version: 20 November 2008
g_file_storage gadget: Number of LUNs=1 
g_file_storage gadget-lun0: ro=0, file: /dev/mmcblk0

/ # lsusb
lsusb: /sys/bus/usb/devices: No such file or directory

/ # cat /lib/modules/2.6.32-17-ridgerun/modules.dep | grep usb
kernel/drivers/usb/otg/nop-usb-xceiv.ko:
kernel/drivers/usb/musb/musb_hdrc.ko: kernel/drivers/usb/otg/nop-usb-xceiv.ko
kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/g_file_storage.ko: kernel/drivers/usb/musb/musb_hdrc.ko kernel/drivers/usb/otg/nop-usb-xceiv.ko
```

On the Ubuntu 10.04 host:

```
$ fgrep USB $DEVDIR/kernel/linux*/.config | grep -v '^#'
CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_MUSB_HDRC=m
CONFIG_USB_MUSB_SOC=y
CONFIG_USB_MUSB_PERIPHERAL=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_MUSB_HDRC=y
CONFIG_USB_TI_CPPI_DMA=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET=m
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW=2
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_SELECTED=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_DUALSPEED=y
CONFIG_USB_FILE_STORAGE=m
CONFIG_USB_OTG_UTILS=y
CONFIG_NOP_USB_XCEIV=m

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Hi-Speed 21-in-1 Flash Card Reader/Writer (Internal/External) 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:003a Lite-On Technology Corp.
```

Comment: Are CONFIG_SYSFS an CONFIG_EMBEDDED included in your kernel config, and is sysfs mounted ? (worth asking for an embedded platform)

Comment: @strnk: CONFIG_SYSFS and CONFIG_EMBEDDED are Y in kernel config and there is a /sys on the target.

Comment: Is this really a *programming* question ? It seems that it would be better suited to http://superuser.com

Comment: @PaulR: Maybe so. Should it be moved? There doesn't seem to be much embedded-linux activity there.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com might be a better fit ? It covers both Unix and Linux and seems to have some embedded Linux questions.

Comment: @PaulR I checked [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) but did not see an embedded linux tag.

Comment: No tag as such - but searching for "embedded linux" turns up a few questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed [usb_composite_msd_acm.patch](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B63baHkhSwOmRGVmQ3lCRjlCLUE) (solved with help from [RidgeRun](https://www.ridgerun.com/)).